# How to perform a create table operation using spark.sql()?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to create a table in oracle database using spark and java. I tried the same using spark's sqlcontext. It is erroring out. Below is the code snippet I am using,

```java
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sqlContext.read().format("oracle").option("walletUri","wallet.zip")
              .option("connectionId","db_high") .option("user", "admin")
              .option("password", "password")
    .option("query","CREATE table admin.test2 (col1 varchar(255))")
    .load();
```

The above code gives the error as "Invalid table name". If I do not use option query, it says option "dbtable"/"query" missing.

I have also tried to execute as

```
spark.sql("CREATE table admin.test2 (col1 varchar(255))")
```

This also  gives same error.

Can someone please help to resolve this error.

Comment: @ Eli Johnes are you using azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula No, I am using oci dataflow.